# Tag silently changed to tag-synonym after posting a question

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78067379/how-to-specify-the-architecture-platform-for-a-channel-for-a-global-pixi-install) specifying the tag [pixi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pixi):

[image]

After I posted it, the tag was silently changed to [pixi.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pixi.js).

[image]

But that's not at all what I wanted. I wanted to create a *new* tag for a *new* tool. I checked whether such a tag existed already, it didn't, so I consciously created it.

I was surprised to find that SO silently renamed the tag. Not even at the "review" stage was this renaming indicated yet, it still said `pixi`.

This feels like a bug. While it might be intended behaviour to avoid creation of duplicate tags, the user should be told that the tag will be renamed, and what it will be renamed to.

I learned that [pixi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pixi) is a tag-synonym of [pixi.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pixi.js). So the issue seems to be that tag-synonyms are not made transparent to users when creating questions. They should get the same info as the target they point to.

[image]

*Disclaimer: It's possible that I should not have tried to create the tag or that I should have named it differently, but my point is solely about the software behaviour, not whether I followed protocol to the letter.*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pixi.js/synonyms

Comment: pixi is a synonym for pixi.js so the system replaced it with the primary value.

Comment: @greg-449 Yes thanks, I also just found out and clarified, but that replacement is unexpected from a user perspective and should be made clear at time of tagging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks problematic indeed. There seems to be no discernable difference between *creating a new* tag versus *using a synonym* tag during the asking phase. In fact, for similarly named synonym and canonical tag the popup during asking even shows the canonical tag like all others, implying they are separate:

[image: tag popup for entering pixi showing the pixi.js tag separately1]

After entering the synonym tag, it still remains with the entered name *just as for creating tags*. There seems to be *no way at all* to check if a tag is a synonym in the asking phase itself.

This is unfortunate, as the asking phase is when authors should check their content; spotting a silent tag change afterwards is much more difficult and unobvious.

It would be nice if there were *some* indication of synonyms during the asking phase. A simple means could be for the synonym to automatically be changed to the canonical tag, making this at least visible during the asking phase.
I'm somewhat sceptical of inheriting (not duplicating) information from the canonical tag. The main information would be the tag description used in the popup, which are notoriously ignored. Still, in the context of synonyms versus new tags this may be sufficient as well.

Comment: Yep. The [principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) ought to be applied.

Comment: Well there is *some* indication it's a synonym, namely the synonym list under [[tag:pixi.js]] lists it as one of it's synonyms, though it's not obvious at all that's what *"also:"* refers to and even if it was, it's not prominent at all.

Comment: There's a _negative_ indication, in that when creating a new tag, you get a confirmation modal asking "do you really want to create a new tag". This doesn't happen for tag-synonyms. That's really the only very hidden indication. But there's no way a normal user would be able to tell from the absence of the modal that they were in fact using a synonym.

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer Interesting, does this show up when actually publishing the question? I’ve only tried writing a dummy question but not publishing it, and noticed no such indicator even with randomly typed "tags".

Comment: I think so yes - only pops up when _actually_ publishing the question

Answer (score 5):

> So the issue seems to be that tag-synonyms are not made transparent to users when creating questions. They should get the same info as the target they point to.

What that *"same info"* you're suggesting seems to be proposing is to allow for tag *duplication*, instead of the synonym logic we have now. These synonyms just redirect to the "main" tag, and automatically get replaced with the main tag. That's the whole point of registering synonyms.

While I agree some feedback that shows when a synonym is replaced could be useful, I don't think it's a significant issue that really warrants time spent on it...

---

Now, if you *disagree* that the tag should be a synonym, you could create a request to un-link the synonym (here on Meta).

You'd need to provide a good excerpt and wiki for the "new" tag, to build a strong case as to why it's different. It would also help if you could link to a list of questions that would benefit from the "new" tag.

Comment: Thanks! My point is entirely about the lack of feedback - I don't care about the particular example.

Comment: The issue is that the automatic replacement could/should happen at the point of entering the synonym, rather than in the backend after the question is submitted. But that would indeed require significant dev work so you're right, probably not worth it.

Comment: "… seems to be proposing is to allow for tag duplication …" As far as I am reading it, there doesn’t need to be a duplicate tag as long as some of the original information (prominently the tag description, or even the canonical tag name) is *visible* via the synonym as well. Right now, entering the tag `pixie` brings up no information at all and looks like an entirely new tag.